# Mysql getting the closest time each day

Tags: mysql

### mysql version 8.0

### table

```
CREATE TABLE `sentiments` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `market_id` int NOT NULL,
  `customer_long` decimal(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `customer_short` decimal(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vol_long` decimal(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `vol_short` decimal(4,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `sentiments_market_id_created_at_index` (`market_id`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24040526 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

### I want to get `market_id`=1 and date(created_at) between '2023-01-01' and '2023-01-31' each day closest 04:00 data, how to build query

it's my sql:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        *,
        ABS( ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP( created_at ) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( created_at, "%Y-%m-%d" ), " 04:00:00" ) ) ) ) AS math_sub,
        DATE_FORMAT( created_at, "%Y-%m-%d" ) AS days 
    FROM
        sentiments 
    WHERE
        DATE( created_at ) BETWEEN '2023-01-01' 
        AND '2023-01-14' 
        AND market_id = 1 
    ORDER BY
        math_sub ASC 
    ) AS b 
GROUP BY
    b.days
```

But it get each day first data

Comment: does "closest" include times that are before 04:00? e.g. 03:59:00 is closest if the next time is at 04:12:23

Comment: @Paul Maxwell, yes, include. 03:59:00 is closest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the row_number() function along with an over() caluse that partitions by the market_id and date, then calculates a difference from 04:00:00 to determine which row is "closest". Note if the time is before 04:00:00 the calculation is reversed so all results are positive integers.

```
select
  *
from (
        select 
           *
          , row_number() over(partition by market_id, date(created_at)
            order by case when time(created_at) >= time('04:00:00') 
                          then time(created_at) - time('04:00:00') 
                          else time('04:00:00') - time(created_at) 
                     end) as rn
        from sentiments
        where created_at >= timestamp('2023-01-01')
        and created_at    < timestamp('2023-02-01')
      ) d
where rn = 1
```

Then you can use the alias (rn in my example) to filter the results for just the closest row (i.e. where rn = 1).

Note that I suggest you **do not use between** for a date range filter, it is much more reliable to use a combination of >= with < as seen above; noting that instead of 2023-01-31 you use the next day 2023-02-01 instead. This ensures that all timestamps prior to the latter date will be included in the range.

Comment: Note that it is possible here to replace your `case...` by `abs(time(created_at) - time('04:00:00'))`